# Auto-displaying a large image on multiple pages

Tags: graphics, page-breaking

I have a long UML diagram, I use the following code.
The figure is about two and a half page long, but only the first page is showing, and the lower part of the figure is missing. How do I display the whole diagram in multiple page?

Exactly what code should I add?

```
\usepackage{graphicx} 
......
\includegraphics[height= 81.3cm, width=18cm]{myImage.png}
\captionof{figure}{Sequence Diagram}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the not showing part. Thanks.

Comment: My best guess is to include the image as many times as needed each time with a suitable `viewport` option (and `clip`). I'll try a "proof of concept".

Comment: Do you mean I use photoshop to cut the image and display it separately?    Don't know how the viewport works, what code should I add?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't a fully automated version, but the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx,adjustbox}

\newsavebox{\bigincbox}
\newlength{\bigincht}
\sbox\bigincbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiger}}
\setlength{\bigincht}{\ht\bigincbox}
{\count0=\bigincht \dimen0=.8\textheight \divide\count0 by \dimen0
 \typeout{You need \number\numexpr\count0+1\relax\space chunks}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\clipbox*{0 {.5\bigincht} {\textwidth} {\bigincht}}{\usebox{\bigincbox}}
\caption{Upper half}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\clipbox*{0 0 {\textwidth} {.5\bigincht}}{\usebox{\bigincbox}}
\caption{Lower half}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here A5 paper and landscape mode are just for giving the example. The `\typeout` will write on the log file how many chunks are needed. Once this is known, it's easy to build the chunks, remembering that the first argument to `\clipbox*` are the lower left corner and upper right corner coordinates determining the rectangle we want to *see*.

The `.8\textwidth` is just to leave some amount of space for the caption.

The `tiger.pdf` image can be found in the documentation directories of PSTricks.

### More concrete code

Let's try with an image 81.3cm high and 18cm wide. It seems that chunks at 90% of the text height should be OK, so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}

\newsavebox{\bigincbox}
\newlength{\bigincht}
\sbox\bigincbox{\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=18cm,height=81.3cm]{tiger}}}
\setlength{\bigincht}{\ht\bigincbox}
{\count0=\bigincht \dimen0=.9\textheight \divide\count0 by \dimen0
 \typeout{You need \number\numexpr\count0+1\relax\space chunks}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\clipbox*{0 {.8\bigincht} {\textwidth} {\bigincht}}{\usebox{\bigincbox}}
\caption{Chunk 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\clipbox*{0 {.6\bigincht} {\textwidth} {0.8\bigincht}}{\usebox{\bigincbox}}
\caption{Chunk 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\clipbox*{0 {.4\bigincht} {\textwidth} {0.6\bigincht}}{\usebox{\bigincbox}}
\caption{Chunk 3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\clipbox*{0 {.2\bigincht} {\textwidth} {0.4\bigincht}}{\usebox{\bigincbox}}
\caption{Chunk 4}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\clipbox*{0 0 {\textwidth} {0.2\bigincht}}{\usebox{\bigincbox}}
\caption{Chunk 5}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The part before `\begin{document}` is what must go in your preamble; remember to load the package **adjustbox**. The code after `\begin{document}` generates the five chunks. Change the captions.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your code. Say my image is myImage.png and it's [width=18cm and height=81.3cm], approximately 2 and a half A4 page.  What code should I add to my existing code? Thanks.

Comment: I would love a fully automated version of this that would work with any image height. I am considering just using a Python script to break my image up into bits.